# Is it possible to apply a function to every region between two "marker" lines?

Tags: region

I have a `.tex` file that looks something like this:

```
$ cat foo.tex

\begin{document}

\begin{question}
lots of
multiline text

with several
paragraphs

of information
\end{question}

other text

\begin{question}
more text

here that i want to

manipulate

easily
\end{question}

\end{document}
```

I want to apply `my-function` to every region occuring between `\begin{question}` and `\end{question}`. Is this easily accomplished in emacs?

Comment: Can we assume that `my-function` accepts arguments for the `beginning` and `end` of the region?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is to use `query-replace-regexp`.
That works if `my-function` takes the region as string and transforms it into the new string such as demonstrated with `upcase` in the following example.

BTW, I do not know how long the texts in the `question` environment may be.

Go to the beginning of the buffer and type <kbd>M-C-%</kbd> for `query-replace-regexp` and input the following FROM and TO strings:

```
\\begin{question}\(\(.\|^Q^J\)*?\)\\end{question}
```

where `^Q^J` means pressing <kbd>C-q</kbd><kbd>C-j</kbd> to insert a line break in the FROM string. Note the use of the [non-greedy](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Regexps.html#index-non_002dgreedy-regexp-matching-999) repetition operator `*?` to match until the next `\end{question}` (`*` would match until the last `\end{question}`).

**→**

```
\\begin{question}\,(upcase \1)\\end{question}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. See library [Zones](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Zones), in particular, function `zz-do-zones` or `zz-map-zones`.

From the Commentary in `zones.el`, section *Define Your Own Commands*:

> Pretty much anything you can do with the Emacs region you can do
>   with a set of zones (i.e., with a non-contiguous "region").  But
>   existing Emacs commands that act on the region do not know about
>   non-contiguous regions.  What you will need to do is define new
>   commands that take these into account.
>
> You can define your own commands that iterate over a list of
>   izones in a given buffer, or over such lists in a set of buffers.
>   Utility functions `zz-izone-limits`, `zz-izone-limits-in-bufs`,
>   and `zz-read-bufs`, `zz-do-zones`, `zz-do-izones`, `zz-map-zones`,
>   and `zz-map-izones` can help with this.
>
> As examples of such commands, if you use library [`highlight.el`](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/download/highlight.el)
>   then you can use `C-x n h` (command `hlt-highlight-regions`) to
>   highlight the izones recorded for the current buffer.  You can use
>   `C-x n H` (command `hlt-highlight-regions-in-buffers`) to do the
>   same across a set of buffers that you specify (or across all
>   visible buffers).  If option `hlt-auto-faces-flag` is non-nil then
>   each zone gets a different face.  Otherwise, all of the zones are
>   highlighted with the same face.  Complementary (unbound) commands
>   `hlt-unhighlight-regions` and `hlt-unhighlight-regions-in-buffers`
>   unhighlight.
>
> Defining your own command can be simple or somewhat complex,
>   depending on how the region is used in the code for the
>   corresponding region-action Emacs command.  The definition of
>   `hlt-highlight-regions` just calls existing function
>   `hlt-highlight-region` once for each recorded zone:

> ```
> (defun hlt-highlight-regions (&optional regions face msgp mousep buffers)
>  "Apply `hlt-highlight-region' to regions in `zz-izones'."
>  (interactive (list (zz-izone-limits zz-izones)
>                     nil
>                     t
>                     current-prefix-arg))
>  (dolist (start+end  regions)
>    (hlt-highlight-region (nth 0 start+end) (nth 1 start+end)
>                          face msgp mousep buffers)))
> ```
>
> That's it - just iterate over `zz-izones` with a function that
>   takes a zone as an argument.  What `zones.el` offers in this
>   regard is a way to easily define a set of buffer zones.

The doc also tells you how to easily create zones from bits of text such as what you describe.  See, for example, function (command) `zz-add-zone`:

> `zz-add-zone` is an interactive Lisp function in `zones.el`.
>
> It is bound to `C-x n a`.
>
> `(zz-add-zone START END &optional VARIABLE NOT-BUF-LOCAL-P SET-VAR-P MSG)`
>
> Add an izone for the region to the izones of `VARIABLE`.
>
> But do not add a zone if it would cover the entire buffer.
>   Return the new value of `VARIABLE`.
>
> This is a destructive operation: The list structure of the variable
>   value can be modified.
>
> `VARIABLE defaults to the value of`zz-izones-var`.
>
> With a prefix arg you are prompted for a different variable to use, in
>   place of the current value of `zz-izones-var`.  The particular prefix
>   arg determines whether the variable, if unbound, is made buffer-local,
>   and whether `zz-izones-var` is set to the variable symbol:
>
> ```
>  prefix arg          buffer-local   set ‘zz-izones-var’
>  ----------          ------------   -------------------
>  Plain ‘C-u’         yes            yes
>  > 0 (e.g. ‘C-1’)    yes            no
>  = 0 (e.g. ‘C-0’)    no             yes
>  < 0 (e.g. ‘C--’)    no             no
> ```
>
> Non-interactively:
>
> - `START` and `END` are as for ‘narrow-to-region’.
> - `VARIABLE` is the optional izones variable to use.
> - Non-nil `NOT-BUF-LOCAL-P` means do not make `VARIABLE` buffer-local.
> - Non-nil `SET-VAR-P` means set `zz-izones-var` to `VARIABLE`.
> - Non-nil `MSG` means echo the zone limits, preceded by string `MSG`.
>
> See also `zz-add-region-as-izone` which also adds the region as an
>   izone, but which has a simpler signature and so can be used as a hook
>   function.  (In particular, it is used on `deactivate-mark-hook` by
>   `zz-auto-add-region-as-izone-mode`, to automatically add the region as
>   an izone each time it is deactivated.)